# Formatting pandas dataframes displayed in jupyter notebooks with comma separated values AND red font for negative values

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, format, jupyter

Executing my script in jupyter notebooks, which returns 4 pandas dataframes as the result. The output tables contain large numbers and visually it is messy to interpret without some formatting. I want to colour negative values in red font and all numbers separated by 1,000 comma delimiters.

If I set the pandas option to display float formats

(`pd.options.display.float_format = '{:20,.0f}'.format`)

I get the comma separated result.

However, if I use CSS styling to to colour negative values red, it seems to overide the float format settings and I lose the comma separators. (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

Example script:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:20,.0f}'.format

def color_negative_red(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color


a = [-1000, -15000, 120000, 3000]
b = [5000, 6000000, -350000, 45000]


df = pd.DataFrame({'A':a, 'B':b})

df1 = df.style.format('{:,.0f}')
df2 = df.style.applymap(color_negative_red)

df1
df2
```

I can return these independently, but I can't perform both formatting events to the same dataframe. There must be a simpler solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the calls!

`df.style.applymap(color_negative_red).format('{:,.0f}')`

This works because the [`Styler.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html) and [`Styler.format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) functions return a [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler) instance - just like [`DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and friends return a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) instance.

```py
import pandas as pd

def color_negative_red(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color

a = [-1000, -15000, 120000, 3000]
b = [5000, 6000000, -350000, 45000]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':a, 'B':b})

# Tadaaa!
df.style.applymap(color_negative_red).format('{:,.0f}')
```

[image: A small table with commas for thousand-separators, and negative numbers in red]

Works at least in Pandas 0.24.2; the styling feature is still provisional :-)